# Каптча в форму отзыва woocommerce в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, recaptcha

Нужно поставить капчу на страницу товара в woocommerce.(вкладка отзывы).
Не пойму какой файл редактировать, уже все перерыл.

Answer (score 0):

Код формы находится в `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php`. Чтобы ваши правки не слетели при обновлении, создайте [дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), скопируйте этот файл в `wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/woocommerce/templates/single-product-reviews.php` и правьте уже его.